# Do emails sent with php email() show up in the sent folder?

Tags: php, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Putting E-mail into “sent” folder after PHP mail function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10975488/putting-e-mail-into-sent-folder-after-php-mail-function)

I've tried sending a few emails to test the php mail() function and it seems like in gmail the emails show up in the sent folder but in other email clients they do not. If I were to send and email from an account like steve.jobs@apple.com to myself, would it be shown in that email's sent folder? Not that I want to do that, but I am just curious.

Comment: No. Doesn't work that way.  SMTP into the account and then sending the message might show up, but typical sendmail won't have that happen.

Comment: No. Not at all. Never (unless they are configured that way). The systems are all independent (although a programmer recently did spoof an email from one google founder to another).

Comment: It's sent from the server. Unless the MTA is configured to provide sort of a Sent folder, no. Most usually, no.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is based on your email provider.

For most email providers, the email will not show up in a "sent items" folder.  The email is sent directly using SMTP, where there is no concept of folders.  When a client keeps a copy in a "sent items" folder, this is a feature of the client only.

Typical SMTP workflow (very high level):

```
> compose message -> "send" (local client may save a copy)
> sendmail(login-info, recip, content) -> SMTP server
> internet magic happens here (email routing) >
> destination server -> POP3/IMAP/web -> recipient's mailbox
```

Gmail is a bit different...  Since they have implemented their own SMTP server, they capture all messages passing through the relay using your account credentials and keep a copy.  It's a bit of a unique feature to them.  Note that this will only show in your Gmail sent items when connecting using IMAP of the browser interface.  If you use a client to access your email, it will not show in the local "sent items" folder.

Gmail-style message workflow (note the only difference at Gmail's server):

```
> compose message -> "send" (local client may save a copy)
> sendmail(login-info, recip, content) -> SMTP server (Gmail server saves a copy)
> internet magic happens here (email routing) >
> destination server -> POP3/IMAP/web -> recipient's mailbox
```

Even for the case of Gmail above, you would not be accessing someone else's "sent items" folder.  Because you provide your login credentials to send email, it will end up in your account's sent items.  Now, if you happen to gain access to another's email credentials for sending emails, that's a different story (and problem for the other person)...

If you have access to an email relay, give it a shot and see what happens.  Try sending an email to yourself as "Bill Gates" or another interesting alias.  If you manage to get the email through, check out the raw headers at the recipient and see what information shows up.

Comment: That's interesting. Couldn't email() be used in a malicious way to send email posing as another person? Is there a way to see that the email was not directly sent from the account in question?

Comment: What you are describing is the difference between an "open mail relay" and one requiring authentication.  Gmail, like any trusted relay, requires credentials to send a message.  You can try sending messages as someone else, however your email account shows up in the mail headers for the recipient.  Servers that truly allow for posing as "anyone" are quickly blacklisted by any reasonable spam filter.  Any message sent through these servers is likely to be rejected at the destination mailbox.

Comment: And even if the server did allow posing as anyone, the email still wouldn't show up in the user's sent folder, correct?

Comment: @PinGran correct...  I have added some content to the answer above to help clarify.

Comment: Great, thanks. So the reason that the email showed up in my sent folder was because I was logged in in that browser? Otherwise it wouldn't have shown up there, right?

Comment: It will show up in your "sent items" for Gmail anytime you use your credentials for the "outgoing mail server" not just when you are logged into the browser.  Even if you set it up in a background script, it will show in your sent items based on your credentials.

Comment: If you have their password, yes.  The outgoing server would be the same, just the credentials you use to send the message change.

Comment: So I just want to make sure that by using this code that there is no way I accidentally put emails in someone's sent folder: `$email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
  $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'] ;
  $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
  mail("test@gmail.com", $subject,
  $message, "From:" . $email); `

Comment: Trust me, you can't unless you have their password.  Or Gmail is broken.  Give it a try and post your findings.  Start a new thread on your progress and any other issues you run into.

Answer (score 2):

**IMAP will save it in the sent folder**, SMTP will not - if you send SMTP from your phone, it'll stay in your phone sent, but no-where else, if you send it to from your home outlook it will stay there.. if you send it via PHP it'll almost certainly not be saved any place (but you can Bcc: it to yourself).. however when you send via gmail you send via an account and they replicate it for you (for free)

Answer (score 0):

No. You are not using your client you are using a SMTP server directly.

You only get copies in your send folder when you are using your own email client directly. Your mail client would usually connect to the SMTP server for you and keep a local copy.