# phpmailer add outgoing mails to outbox

Tags: php, email

I'm using the following script to send out mails with php

```
$status = $_POST['status'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$from = "info@example.com";
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
$headers  .= "From: $from\r\n";
$recipment = $_POST['to'];


if (mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers)){

    return 'Email sent!';

}
```

I would like save a copy of all outgoing mails to the used accounts outbox. 
Which php mailer functions are available to achieve this.

Comment: `$headers .= 'Bcc: your_email@your_domain.com' . "\r\n";` will send you a copy too

Comment: Probable duplicates: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10975488/putting-e-mail-into-sent-folder-after-php-mail-function

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561495/sent-mails-with-phpmailer-dont-go-to-sent-imap-folder/8561849

Comment: I suspect it will depend on the available protocols. SMTP, IMAP, Exchange, ...

Comment: the first suggestion is fast and dirty workaround but I would like to separate the mail correspondence so I suppose I should build on imap a function which can take care of it

Comment: I have been trying to use phpmailer but till now no luck. The email is getting send it but I don't see my mail in outbox