# imap_fetchbody can't handle mails sent with phpmailer?

Tags: php, imap, phpmailer

I am sending some emails with phpmailer with the regular example on their website.

the email is sent, and it arrives perfectly to the sent address.

after the mail is sent, I am saving the email to my sent items folder with imap_append, using the info of this answer [Sent mails with phpmailer don't go to "Sent" IMAP folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561495/sent-mails-with-phpmailer-dont-go-to-sent-imap-folder)

and in third place, I am creating a custom made webmail which reads my imap folders.

the problem is that I can't get the html body of the email sent correctly.

When I open the mail on sent items on thunderbird, or my phone, the body is shown perfectly.

but when I try to get the html body with php_imap functions I can't make it!!.

I created an isolated file to fetch the body of the msg like this:

```
$body =  imap_fetchbody($conn,3392,1,FT_UID);
```

that returns this:

```
 --b1_9db4e4310d1b141cbec79dd7de22f70b Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit Ã¡ Ã© Ã­ Ã± Ã‘ REMOVED CONTENT --------------------- klfasjdkl adj skldj klfdj akfdsj lkfdasjfkl dasjf --b1_9db4e4310d1b141cbec79dd7de22f70b Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit Ã¡ Ã© Ã­ Ã± Ã‘

 REMOVED CONTENT

  --------------------- 

  klfasjdkl adj skldj klfdj akfdsj lkfdasjfkl dasjf --b1_9db4e4310d1b141cbec79dd7de22f70b--
```

If I try

```
$body =  imap_fetchbody($conn,3392,1.2,FT_UID);
```

don't get anything

If I try

```
$body =  imap_fetchbody($conn,3392,2,FT_UID);
```

don't get anything, it seems that PHPMailer creating the emailbody in a way that imap_fetchbody can't handle?

thank you

Comment: I think it has created them in a way that your servers MIME parser can't handle.  You can always fetch the entire message (rather than a part number) and parse it yourself.

Comment: Do you know if there is an alternative to phpmailer ? That maybe can work with what I have?